# Почему изменение возвращаемого значения метода выбрасывает ошибку?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, dao

Реализую в Spring Data JPA метод `delete` и возник такой вопрос, почему, если метод возвращает `boolean`:

```java
    @Query(name = Meal.DELETE)
    boolean delete(@Param("id")Integer id,@Param("userId") Integer userId);

    @Override
    public boolean delete(int id, int userId) {
        return crudRepository.delete(id, userId);
    }
```

То компилятор выбрасывает `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException`, но если я меняю возвращаемое значение на `Integer`, а метод `delete` добавляю сравнение (!= 0), то ошибок не возникает и метод корректно выполняется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Некорректное использование АПИ приводит к такому исключению.

> Исключение возникает при неправильном использовании API, например при невозможности «скомпилировать» объект запроса, который необходимо скомпилировать перед выполнением.
> Это представляет собой проблему в нашей структуре доступа к данным Java, а не в базовой инфраструктуре доступа к данным.

---

Дело в том что метод удаления не может возвращать `boolean`, поскольку возвращает количество удаленных записей.